# Delphi - Conditional Compile If Map File Detailed is used/checked

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

In Delphi linker tab (project option), there is a "Map file" option. I need to know a way to use with $IFOPT to detect the option is specified when compiling in order to have certain codes to be compiled.

```
{$IFOPT MapFileOption.....}
{$ENDIF}
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to test this from code using `$IFOPT`.

The reason for this is that the map file generation happens post-compile. It is a link time step. So, you can take compiled dcu files and link them into an executable, generating a map file at that point. You can do this repeatedly, choosing different map file options each time, using the same dcu files. So, at the point of compilation, it is not known which map file option will be used.

I suppose the easiest way to see this is to consider the code in the Delphi RTL. That is supplied to you in the form of dcu files compiled by the vendor. You can build your executable with detail map, and I build mine without. But we both used the same RTL dcu files.